# How I can sent ETH using alias 0xEe address?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, chainlink, transfer

How do I send ether through a smart contract using the 0xE alias for it in transactions from the UI? I've been sitting and racking my head for the fifth day. Here's an example of my function, tell me what I'm doing wrong? @chainlink

```
contract BatchTransfer is Ownable {
address constant _ETH_ADDRESS_ = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;
address public immutable _WETH_;

using SafeMath for uint256;
using SafeCast for int256;

ICore coreContract;

uint256 private feesRatePercent;

constructor(address _coreContractAddress, address weth) {
    require(
        _coreContractAddress != address(0),
        "BulkifyProtocol: Core contract address cannot be zero"
    );
    require(weth != address(0), "BulkifyProtocol: weth address invalid");
    coreContract = ICore(_coreContractAddress);
    _WETH_ = weth;
}

event BatchTransferCompleted(
    address indexed receiver,
    address[] tokenAddresses,
    uint256[] amounts
);

///Main Function for with trandfer logic
/// @param tokenAddresses adresses as [] of sended tokens
/// @param amounts amounts as [BigNumbers] of sended tokens
/// @param receiver address as receiver
function batchTransfer(
    address[] memory tokenAddresses,
    uint256[] memory amounts,
    address receiver
) public payable {
    require(
        !isPausedInCore(),
        "BulkifyProtocol: BatchTransfer is Paused in Core"
    );

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
        if (tokenAddresses[i] == _ETH_ADDRESS_) {
            IWETH(_WETH_).deposit{value: amounts[i]}();
            _handleTransfer(_WETH_, amounts[i], receiver, true);
        } else {
            _handleTransfer(tokenAddresses[i], amounts[i], receiver, false);
        }
    }

    emit BatchTransferCompleted(receiver, tokenAddresses, amounts);
}

/// Before transfer will be success we working there with fees.
/// If you transfer ETH it's will be wraped for money saving and unwraped in exit
/// @param token address of sent tokens
/// @param amount amount of sent tokens
/// @param receiver address of receiver
/// @param isETH return bool 'true' if you wanna transfer Native Token
function _handleTransfer(
    address token,
    uint256 amount,
    address receiver,
    bool isETH
) internal {
    uint256 commissionAmount = amount.mul(feesRatePercent).div(100);
    uint256 receiverAmount = amount.sub(commissionAmount);
    if (isETH) {
        require(
            IWETH(_WETH_).transfer(
                coreContract.safeWallet(),
                commissionAmount
            ),
            "BulkifyProtocol: Commission transfer failed"
        );

        IWETH(_WETH_).withdraw(receiverAmount);
        require(
            payable(receiver).send(receiverAmount),
            "BulkifyProtocol: ETH transfer failed"
        );
    } else {
        require(
            IERC20(token).transferFrom(
                msg.sender,
                receiver,
                receiverAmount
            ),
            "BulkifyProtocol: Token transfer failed"
        );
        require(
            IERC20(token).transferFrom(
                msg.sender,
                coreContract.safeWallet(),
                commissionAmount
            ),
            "BulkifyProtocol: Commission transfer failed"
        );
    }
}

function isPausedInCore() public view returns (bool) {
    return coreContract.modulePaused("BatchTransfer");
}

function setFeesRatePercent(uint256 _feesRatePercent) external onlyOwner {
    feesRatePercent = _feesRatePercent;
}

function getFeesRatePercent() public view returns (uint256) {
    return feesRatePercent;
}

receive() external payable {}
}
```

Comment: Am confused - the question says "in transactions from the UI" - so you're trying to send a ether to the contract at address `_ETH_ADDRESS_` ...but if its from the front end UI the Solidity is not what we need to look at?  

Could you please rephrase the question to be clear on what the workflow and operations intended are?